# Execute a local bash variable inside double quotes

Tags: bash, for-loop, echo

Hypothetically I have four webservers that I need to add a line of HTML to a file. As you can see I need the integer to appear after **cluster=**

```
for i in 01 02 03 04; do ssh web.${i}.domain.com 'echo "<img src=beacon.gif?cluster=${i}>" >> /var/www/index.html'; done
```

How can this be accomplished?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please note the `'` before and after `${i}`:

```
for i in 01 02 03 04; do
    ssh web.${i}.domain.com 'echo "<img src=beacon.gif?cluster='${i}'>" >> /var/www/index.html'
done
```

**Edit:** There is a huge difference between quoting in shell and string literals in programming languages. In shell, "quoting is used to remove the special meaning of certain characters or words to the shell" (bash manual). The following to lines are identical to bash:

```
'foo bar'
foo' 'bar
```

There is no need to quote the alphabetic characters - but it enhances the readability. In your case, only special characters like `"` and `<` must be quoted. But the variable `$i` contains only digits, and this substitution can be safely done outside of quotes.

Comment: @nosid: I think it would be worthwhile to explain what's going on there. After all you end up doing a string concatenation and your solution is different from the other two. Still +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in 01 02 03 04
do
  ssh web.${i}.domain.com "echo \"<img src=beacon.gif?cluster=${i}>\" >> /var/www/index.html
done
```

Basically, just use double quotes, but you'll have to escape the inner ones.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
"echo \"<img src=beacon.gif?cluster=${i}>\" >> /var/www/index.html"
```